# merge two data frames in R based on email address

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a data file that has my subject responses listed by their emails and I have another file with each subject email next to his/her subject ID. How do replace all the emails in the main data file with their subject IDs?

Comment: have you tried importing the files into r and writing some code? that's your first step and if you're still stuck, try a few google queries and if you're still stuck, update your question with your code.

Comment: read files into R and use function `merge`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/merge)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sydney. Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that's great about R is the ease with which one can create a minimal, complete and verifiable example. For this question, it's a simple matter of generating some example data, reading it into R and working out a potential solution. We'll create a list of student email addresses, IDs, and a separate data set containing exam scores.

```
nameData <- "email ID
Alicia@gmail.com 1
Jane@aol.com 2
Thomas@msn.com 3
Henry@yale.edu 4
LaShawn@uga.edu 5
"
examData <- "email exam1 exam2 exam3
Alicia@gmail.com 98 77 87
Jane@aol.com 99 88 93
Thomas@msn.com 73 62 73
Henry@yale.edu 100 98 99
LaShawn@uga.edu 84 98 92"

names <- read.table(text=nameData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
exams <- read.table(text=examData,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# merge data and drop email, which is first column 
mergedData <- merge(names,exams)[,-1]
mergedData[order(mergedData$ID),]
```

...and the output, sorted by ID:

```
> mergedData[order(mergedData$ID),]
  ID exam1 exam2 exam3
1  1    98    77    87
3  2    99    88    93
5  3    73    62    73
2  4   100    98    99
4  5    84    98    92
>
```

Comment: Apologies for not being specific! This was all helpful. I am running my analyses in R and am still not sure if merge is the best function. I have experience sampling data with several thousand rows and only 30 unique email address. The emails are in the first column plus many other variables such as sampling time and survey responses. In a separate data frame is the subject ID and subject email. I'd like to replace all the email addresses in the large frame with only the subject ID. They are not in order and again there are far more rows in my experience sampling data frame than the email one.

Comment: ema$email <- log$ID if log$email == ema$email where ema is a larger data frame with multiple entries per email and the log frame has only the ID and email